# Calling a multiplexer select from a node

Tags: ros, services

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm wondering how I would go about calling the multiplexer select from inside a node instead of using the command line tool. Are there any examples on how to accomplish this as I cannot find any?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202390/calling-a-multiplexer-select-from-a-node/) by [Aracanid](https://answers.ros.org/users/20303/aracanid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just incase anyone ever has a similar question I finally realised what I had been doing wrong while going through the source code for mux_select and it appears to be working now. Simply follow their example here:

https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/topic_tools/scripts/mux_select

---

Originally posted by [Aracanid](https://answers.ros.org/users/20303/aracanid/) with karma: 51 on 2015-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0